# How to WCF Rest stream URI via browser

Tags: wcf, streaming

I have a WCF Rest Service which returns a stream hosted in IIS . This is accessible via a .net client app but not via the web browser.

I have the following in the web.config:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedHttp" transferMode="StreamedResponse" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SvcMetaData" name="Services.StreamService">
        <endpoint name="stream" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedHttp" contract="Services.IStreamDetails" />
        <endpoint name="wsdl" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>
```

The interface is as below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStreamDetails
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Items/{itemID}")]
    Stream GetDetails(string itemID);
}
```

The implementation of the service is as below:

```
public Stream GetItem (string ItemID)
{
    string filePath= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"];
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

    return File.OpenRead(filePath);
}
```

I am able to access this from a .Net client using:

```
ItemService.ItemDetailsClient client = new ItemDetailsClient();
var v = client.GetDetails("test");
v.CopyTo(new FileStream(@".\temp.doc", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
```

When I call this from a web browser, I get a blank webpage. WCF trace log shows the following exception:

```
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
```

Comment: If you are trying to access the response from a web browser you would need to setup an endpoint the exposes an webHttpBinding which supports REST.

Comment: This makes sense but now it is turning into a different problem all together. I need to publish one interface via webHttpBinding and another interface for streaming large binary data.  If I use basicHttpbinding then I can't test via browser. If I use webHttpBinding then I can't use MTOM encoding.

Comment: setup 2 different endpoints with the needed bindings to cover all scenarios

Comment: Thanks but this is not allowed. Here is a snippet of the error message "If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance."

Comment: You would need to distinguish the address of each endpoint. Posting on how you config entry looks might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on your local IIS?

Whenever I've seen that error, its been resolved by running on my local IIS webserver.